# when will riffle be release? anyone know? riffle is new technology that provide better anonymity than tor

Tags: anonymity

when will riffle be release? anyone know? riffle is new technology that provide better anonymity than tor look at this news. it has been over half year since riffle in development http://news.mit.edu/2016/stay-anonymous-online-0711

Comment: On what principle it is based on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Riffle, hOR.NET and many other *promising on paper* projects are seem to be either a hoax, or a stale-development ones. No release date for all of them - even for the source, that makes most of concerns about of theit actual existence very well-grounded. As for me - I recommend you just read the paper, study it(if it contains any *real* piece of data, not just promises and speed tables) and don't waste your time waiting for them. If they will ever be released - then it's time to return your mind focus on it. Keep it real

Comment: so far is tor browser provide best anonymity? I think you are right. due to riffle over half year still no release just a paper

Comment: could I ask I2P and tor browser which provide more anonymity?

Comment: Tor browser provides a good amount of anonymity, but it's still a browser, so it must be an isolated VM to be safer. I2P is good too - I'm using it myself, with Tor and isolated VM. But I2P is focused on in-darknet anonymity, it's not purposed for reaching out the Internet as the primary task.

Comment: hi Alexey I got riffle's project paper could you please read http://people.csail.mit.edu/devadas/pubs/riffle.pdf is this real or just a hoax

Comment: OK, I will add my review here, but tomorrow or a day after tomorrow - I have some code to do and will have time only after complete and some sleep as well.

Comment: @broly it's a mature draft paper, so some code prototypes can physically exist for riffle. But speaking practically - it's *too theoretic* for now, I expect it's a pre-alpha release description mixed with a strong concept research. As my experience shows, it can take up to a year - if this time will be fully dedicated to the development process - to release the working product in it's late beta stage. I hope that it won't die in the table case as HORNET - it has a good proposal paper too, but still it's dead

Comment: Okay thank you Alexey understand :) could I ask when tor browser update it has been over one month with no update just tor update not the browser

Comment: Tor browser bundle contains tor binary, so if you want to use latest tor binary - just download an expert bundle and replace GeoIP bases and the binary in your setup. It's just a drop-in

Comment: could you teach me Alexey please I already gave you good reputation thank you